# Request for resolving the error cannot convert from void to HSSFCell

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to read the data from an excel file which has formulas and writing the data to a particular column of another excel but by using the below code, i am getting an error message like : Cannot Convert from void to HSSFCell at line 68.

```
 @Test 

    public void SampleCustNumFormat() throws Exception { 

    String [] myXL = getExcelData();

    //Write Data into Excel.


   //See what has been read from Excel
    System.out.println (" Before Loop " + myXL[1]);

    for (int i=0; i<xRows; i++){
          System.out.println (" Cust Num " + myXL[i]);
    }

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream ("C:\\SCE docs\\Automation\\TestExcelData.xls");
    HSSFWorkbook myWB = new HSSFWorkbook(); 
    HSSFSheet sheet = myWB.getSheetAt(0); 

    for (int k=1; k<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); k++)
    {
    HSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(1).createCell(2).setCellValue(myXL[k]);
    }
    myWB.write(out);
    out.close();
 }




public  String [] getExcelData() throws Exception{

 String [] tabArray=null;

            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("C:\\SCE docs\\Automation\\CustomerAccount_Information.xls"); 
            HSSFWorkbook myWB = new HSSFWorkbook(fi); 
            HSSFSheet mySheet = myWB.getSheetAt(0); 

            FormulaEvaluator evaluator = myWB.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

            xRows = mySheet.getLastRowNum()+1; 
           tabArray = new String [xRows]; 

            for (int i=0;i<xRows;i++) 
            { 
            HSSFRow row = mySheet.getRow(i); 
                HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(3); 
                CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
                String value = evaluateFormula(cellValue);
                tabArray[i]=value;
            }
            return tabArray;

            }





private String evaluateFormula(CellValue cellValue) throws Exception{

int type = cellValue.getCellType();

Object result=null;

switch (type) {

case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
    result = cellValue.getBooleanValue();
     break;
 case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
     result = cellValue.getNumberValue();
     break;
 case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
     result = cellValue.getStringValue();
     break;
 case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
     break;
 case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
     break;


 // CELL_TYPE_FORMULA will never happen
 case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA: 
     break;
  }

return result.toString();
 }
            }
```

Comment: Akokskis is right. What I have suggested you on your previous post was my mistake. I have updated the code there.

Comment: OR you can write `sheet.getRow(1).createCell(2).setCellValue(myXL[k]);` in place of `HSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(1).createCell(2).setCellValue(myXL[k]);`

Comment: The above suggestion got rid of the void error but i am facing problem in writing the data to an excel. I am getting Illegal Argument Exception: Sheet index(0) is out of range (0..-1)

Comment: Here i am reading data from an existing file and write the data to a particular column of another existing file . Help me in achieving the result. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These lines are causing the trouble:

```
for (int k=1; k<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); k++)
{
HSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(1).createCell(2).setCellValue(myXL[k]);
}
```

Here you are getting the first row out of the sheet, creating a cell at index 2 and then setting the cell value... and assigning all of that to a `Cell`!  However, `setCellValue` returns a `void` (as seen in the [API](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellValue%28java.lang.String%29)).  So basically, you need to split those lines into two like this:

```
for (int k=1; k<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); k++)
{
HSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(1).createCell(2);
cell.setCellValue(myXL[k]);
}
```

Doing it this way, you'll first create the cell and assign that to `cell`.  Then, you can set the value.

Edit: Alternatively, you can (as pointed out by Sankumarsingh) just not assign that value and do it all in one line like this:

```
for (int k=1; k<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); k++)
{
sheet.getRow(1).createCell(2).setCellValue(myXL[k]);
}
```

Comment: The above suggestion got rid of the void error but i am facing problem in writing the data to an excel. I am getting Illegal Argument Exception: Sheet index(0) is out of range (0..-1)

Comment: Here i am reading data from an existing file and write the data to a particular column of another existing file . Help me in achieving the result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1564024 - well, you didn't actually create a sheet!  Instead of `HSSFSheet sheet = myWB.getSheetAt(0);`, try: `HSSFSheet sheet = myWB.createSheet()`.  You're also going to have issues with this line: `for (int k=1; k<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); k++)`, as `sheet` won't have any rows in it.  You should probably base the iteration of that for loop off of the length of `myXL`.

Comment: I dont want to create sheet as i want to write the data into an existing sheet of an excel file which has data in few columns and i want to write this new data to a particular column of that existing excel file.Please let me know if it is not clear i would explain further detail.

Comment: @user1564024 oooh, ok.  You need to create the `Workbook` with a `File` like so: `Workbook myWb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("C:\\SCE docs\\Automation\\TestExcelData.xls"));`.  Without doing that, you're simply creating a blank `Workbook` which is why you're getting the `IllegalArgumentException`.  You can also create the `Workbook` it with a `FileInputStream`, if you prefer.

Comment: I have tried creating a workbook but i am getting an error message like " Factory cannot be resolved or is not a field. I have imported all the required JARs but not sure which import i am missing or do i need initialize workbookfactory???.. Could u please suggest what need to be done.

Comment: I have an ooxml jar which resolved the issue. Thanks for your valuable suggestions. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

After Akoksis, I have to reframe your programe. please check it out whether its working or not for you

```
@Test 

public void SampleCustNumFormat() throws Exception { 
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("C:\\SCE docs\\Automation\\CustomerAccount_Information.xls"); 
    HSSFWorkbook myWB = new HSSFWorkbook(fi); 
    HSSFSheet mySheet = myWB.getSheetAt(0); 
    String [] myXL = getExcelData(myWB);
   //See what has been read from Excel
    System.out.println (" Before Loop " + myXL[1]);
    for (int i=0; i<xRows; i++){
          System.out.println (" Cust Num " + myXL[i]);
    }
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("C:\\SCE docs\\Automation\\TestExcelData.xls");
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file); 

    for (int k=1; k<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); k++){
          wb.getSheet(0).getRow(1).createCell(2).setCellValue(myXL[k]);
    }
    //Write Data into Excel.
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream ("C:\\SCE docs\\Automation\\TestExcelData.xls");
    wb.write(out);
    out.close();
}



public  String [] getExcelData(HSSFWorkbook myWB) throws Exception{
    String [] tabArray=null;
    HSSFSheet mySheet = myWB.getSheetAt(0); 
    FormulaEvaluator evaluator = myWB.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
    xRows = mySheet.getLastRowNum()+1; 
    tabArray = new String [xRows]; 
    for (int i=0;i<xRows;i++){ 
        HSSFRow row = mySheet.getRow(i); 
        HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(3); 
        CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
        String value = evaluateFormula(cellValue);
        tabArray[i]=value;
    }
    return tabArray;
}





private String evaluateFormula(CellValue cellValue) throws Exception{
    int type = cellValue.getCellType();
    Object result=null;
    switch (type) {
        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
             result = cellValue.getBooleanValue();
             break;
        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
             result = cellValue.getNumberValue();
             break;
        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
             result = cellValue.getStringValue();
             break;
        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
             break;
        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
             break;
         // CELL_TYPE_FORMULA will never happen
         case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA: 
             break;
    }
    return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, The above code writes the data into a new excel but not into an existing excel.Help me in writing the data in an existing excel

Comment: This should read data from `CustomerAccount_Information.xls` and write on `TestExcelData.xls`. Isn't it what you want??

Comment: I want to read the data from customeraccount_information.xls and write the data to a specific column of an existing file(TestExcelData) which has data in another columns but when i use the above approach it reads the data from customeraccount_information.xls and write data to an testexceldata which is new file

Comment: Updated the `SampleCustNumFormat()` method. Please check it once.

Comment: I have used workbook factory and there after i could able to write the data correctly into the desired excel.Thanks for the time you have taken to correct the code. really appreciate your help.